# npm cannot recognize dot slash notation in Windows

Tags: testing, npm, cmd

I have the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "foo": "./node_modules/bar",
    }
```

An `npm run test` command produces the following:

`'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: The directory separator is ``\`` on Windows and not `/` as on Linux/Mac as it can be read in the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). The batch file `npm.cmd` is not good enough coded to fix such syntax errors automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was correct, works in Git Bash:

> The directory separator is \ on Windows and not / as on Linux/Mac as it can be read in the Microsoft documentation about Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces. The batch file npm.cmd is not good enough coded to fix such syntax errors automatically. - Mofi

You'll need to escape the backslashes as well to work properly:

```
"scripts": {
    "foo": ".\\node_modules\\bar",
}
```